# Null значения в ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Есть ArrayList содержащий некоторые записи и null значения в конце списка. 
Как можно проверить, что null значения находятся в конце списка?

Comment: Приведите минимальный компилируемый код, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так

```
    public static boolean endsWithNulls(List<Object> lst) {
        if (lst == null || lst.isEmpty() || lst.get(lst.size()-1) != null) {
            return false;
        }
        boolean nullsFinished = false;
        for (int i = lst.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (lst.get(i) != null) {
                nullsFinished = true;
            } else {
                if (nullsFinished) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchFieldException {
        System.out.println(endsWithNulls(Arrays.asList(1, 2, null))); //true
        System.out.println(endsWithNulls(Arrays.asList(1, 2, null, null, null))); //true
        System.out.println(endsWithNulls(Arrays.asList(null, 2, null, null, null))); //false
        System.out.println(endsWithNulls(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))); //false
}
```

Comment: Не null значение, а null значениЯ. Вы проверяете последний элемент.

Comment: окай, щас поправлю

Comment: Как подправить код, что бы в случае если в листе нет нулл значений вообще, возвращало true?

Comment: Можно вставить между первой проверкой и циклом: if (!lst.contains(null)) return true;

Answer (score 2):

что-то вроде того:

```
List<..> xs;
int indexOfFirstNull = xs.indexOf(null);
if (indexOfFirstNull != -1) {
   if (indexOfFirstNull = xs.size() -1) return true;
   return xs.sublist(indexOfFirstNull + 1, xs.size()).stream().allMatch(x -> x == null);
} else { /* нуля не было? */ }
```